# Jump to specific character in a line with Vimscript

Tags: vim

I want to bind TAB in insert mode to jump to position after ')', if it exists after cursor in the active line, and otherwise it should just act as a normal TAB. I have not managed to find search or find functions in Vimscript that limit the search to a single line, and I still wouldn't know how to check if the character was found. So in pseudo code it should look like:

```
inoremap <TAB> :if (char_in_line(')')) | cursor_on_char() | a (append) | else '\t' | endif
```

Comment: Did you read `:help search()`?

Answer (score 2):

To get the current line text,  use `getline('.')`. Then you can easily
check if there is a `)` with  `match()`, which will return -1 if there
is none or the `)` position if there is one.

With  a  `^R`  in  insert  mode,  you can  insert  the  result  of  an
expression. Then,  use the test  with a traditional `a?b:c`  (see help
for `expr1`) and  return the appropriate character  (tab or movement).
To return the  movement, you can use `^O` in  insert mode which allows
you to run  a normal mode command without  leaving insert. Technically
you can  run only one command,  while done interactively. But  in this
case, it will be  inserted at once by Vim and you  can do two commands
at  once: `f)`  to move  to  next `)`  and  `l` to  adjust the  cursor
position.

Putting it all together:

```
:inoremap <tab> <c-r>=match(getline('.'), ')') < 0 ? "\t" : "\<c-o>f)l"<cr>
```

The  only remaining  bit is  that  this test  doesn't consider  cursor
position. But since  `match()` returns the position of  the match, you
can compare  the result with  `getcurpos()[2]` (see the help  for this
function too) and of course adjust the logic accordingly.

However, for anything more complicated than that, I recommend building
this in  a function where  you manipulate  the cursor position  as you
wish (help is your friend, specially `:h function-list`) and then call
this function in your map.

```
inoremap <tab> <esc>:call InsertSmartTab()<cr>
```